# C# class design for JSON data structure

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am writing some code to meet a spec for a government department.  I can't parse a section in to classes in C#

**Sample**

```
{
    "tdeVersion": "2.0",
    "batchId": "ABC20190803",
    "deviceRecords": [
        {
            "device": {
                "id": "1234"
            },
            "records": [
                {
                    "type": "POSITION",
                    "number": 1234,
                    "dateTime": "2019-01-23T03:04:05Z",
                    "position": {
                        "latitude": -36.00001,
                        "longitude": 140
                    },
                    "speed": 98.7,
                    "receiptDateTime": "2019-01-23T03:04:05Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My problem is the deviceRecords collection element.  Normally I'd use something like List.  What should I use here?  I've already mapped the rest to classes.

Comment: DeviceRecords is an array of objects. One such object contains two properties: `device`, an object, and `records`, a list of objects. What's the issue?

Comment: so object[] DeviceRecords?

Comment: Well, I'd suggest declaring a class that matches the shape of a single deviceRecord object and then have an array/list of that as a property in the parent object.

Comment: class DeviceRecords { object[]? }

Comment: I think you might be misreading your JSON. `{` ... `}` signifies an object - you can represent this as a `class` in C#. `[`...`]` signifies an array - you can represent this as a collection type (list, array, etc.) in C#. Everything else is your object is a property, be that a `string`, `int`, a class that you define, a generic list, etc.

Comment: I've got it.  Would you like to post an answer I can accept?

Comment: Done. I've walked you through each step of creating the class structure to deserialize to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this JSON:

```json
{
    "tdeVersion": "2.0",
    "batchId": "ABC20190803",
    "deviceRecords": [
        {
            "device": {
                "id": "1234"
            },
            "records": [
                {
                    "type": "POSITION",
                    "number": 1234,
                    "dateTime": "2019-01-23T03:04:05Z",
                    "position": {
                        "latitude": -36.00001,
                        "longitude": 140
                    },
                    "speed": 98.7,
                    "receiptDateTime": "2019-01-23T03:04:05Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Let's start by creating the inner-most object first: position.

```cs
public class Position
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

Then we can create the record object that contains it:

```cs
public class RecordEntity // record is a keyword in C#, so we'll call this RecordEntity
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("dateTime")]
    public DateTime DateAndTime { get; set; } // DateTime is a keyword
    public double Speed { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReceiptDateAndTime { get; set; }
}
```

And then the device object:

```cs
public class Device
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Next we can make the object that contains Device and RecordEntity:

```cs
public class DeviceRecords
{
    public Device Device { get; set; }
    // records is an array so we need a collection type in C#
    public List<RecordEntity> Records { get; set; }
}
```

Then we need to create the outer-most object to house these:

```cs
public class Batch
{
    public string TdeVersion { get; set; }
    public string BatchId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("deviceRecords")]
    public List<DeviceRecords> DevicesWithRecords { get; set; } // deviceRecords seemed confusing
}
```

Now we should be able to deserialize to `Batch`:

```cs
string json = "{\"tdeVersion\":\"2.0\",\"batchId\":\"ABC20190803\",\"deviceRecords\":[{\"device\":{\"id\":\"1234\"},\"records\":[{\"type\":\"POSITION\",\"number\":1234,\"dateTime\":\"2019-01-23T03:04:05Z\",\"position\":{\"latitude\":-36.00001,\"longitude\":140},\"speed\":98.7,\"receiptDateTime\":\"2019-01-23T03:04:05Z\"}]}]}";

// if you're using JSON.NET:
Batch batch = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Batch>(json);

// if you're using System.Text.Json:
Batch batch = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Batch>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to parse the content to "JObject" instead of List, that will more easier to use than List, then you can calling then like

```
JObject Res = JObject.Parse(jsondata);
Response.Write(Res["deviceRecords"][0]["device"]["id"]);
```

or if you dun want to use index, you can use foreach to loop Res["deviceRecords"].

Comment: This is me generating output files to send to the department.  I have access to the data on our side.